# copy string function, copied string not printing in function itself

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a program of copy string using pointers dynamically. The function is called from `main()` and copied string is displayed in `main()` but when I tried to display the copied string in the function itself then there is only cursor blinking.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void copystr(char *p,char *s);

int main ()
{    
    char str[50],*ptr,*p;
    printf("enter the string\n");
    gets(str);

    ptr=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    copystr(ptr,str);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void copystr(char *p,char *s)
{          
    s=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    while(*s!='\0')
    {   *p=*s;
        s++;
        p++;
    }
    *p='\0';

    printf("copy string is  %s", p);   // if i display this printf in main 'p' prints fine, but here no output
    free(p);
}
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: `s=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
         while(*s!='\0')` is going to get you confused later. I think you are mixing up your `s` and you `p`.

Comment: 1) remove `s=malloc(50*sizeof(char));` 2) add `char *org = p;` then `printf(..., org);free(org);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     printf("copy string is  %s", p);   // if i display this printf in main 'p' prints fine, but here no output
```

Because `p` does not point at the beginning of the string in that function (even assuming you fixed the issue with `s=malloc(50*sizeof(char))`).

Also if you:

```
   free(p);
```

like you have it now, you won't be able to use the original `ptr` in main too.

Comment: i don't want to print in 'main' , i want to print in this function or i tried to print in this function but failed as i successfully printed in 'main'

Comment: @madara: then store value of `p` in temporary pointer. and print that temporary pointer, when you are done copying string. e.g. `char*tmp = p;` use `p` afterwards like you have now, but *print* `tmp`.

Comment: it did, thanks but why storing in temp and using only p and print temp
help me out

Comment: @madara: because when you do `p++` it does not point at the beginning of the string anymore, `p` points to the next character in string and so on. When you try to print string, you pass it address where the string starts. In your case you pass address at the end of string due to several `p++`. PS if you `free(p)` - you are freeing original pointer `ptr` too

Comment: so that's why its printing in main because i'm using ptr to print the copied string

Comment: @madara: didn't get your last sentence but it might print in main because there `ptr` points at the beginning of the string. Actually I am surprised `ptr` works in main after call to function because like I said `free(p)` frees also `ptr`

Answer (score 3):

**Issues**

1. Never use `gets()`. It suffers seriously from buffer overflow issues. Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
2. The `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` in `C`. Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is effectively redundant.
3. First, you're receiving `s` as one of the incoming parameter in `copystr()`, then immediately you're doing `s=malloc(50*sizeof(char));`. Here, you're losing the incoming pointer. All further operations are pointless.
4. In case of failure, `malloc()` returns NULL. Using the returned pointer further in that case will cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
5. `malloc()` returns uninitialized memory, if successful. After `malloc()`, directly writing `while(*s!='\0')` which is, reading the content of uninitialized memory. Invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
6. Inside `copystr()`, you're incrementing the received pointer `p`, and after copying you're adding the null-terminator. So the current value of `p` points to the null-terminator. Hence, using `p` in the `printf()` won't give you any output, at all.

**solution**

1. Add a NULL check on `ptr` after `malloc()` to check for success.
2. Remove the `malloc()` on `s` inside `copystr()`.
3. Use another temporary pointer to hold the incoming value of `p`. After you've used `p` to get the value stored, use the temporary pointer to print the copied string.

Comment: thanks for answer sir, i removed the malloc but still no output

Comment: i did what you have said, but no output 
       
            void copystr(char *p,char *s)
       {       char *temp;
               temp=p;
        
            while(*s!='\0')
        {   *temp=*s;
               s++;
               temp++;
               }
               *temp='\0';
              
               
             printf("copy string is  %s", temp);
               free(p)   }

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the malloc in the function - it will get rid of the data that you pass to the function in str - try rerunning you code with out that line in the function

remove the line

```
s=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
```

Also you probably want to put something in main to print out the function you have copied after you have called your copying routine so you know that it worked. (also note the problem of printing the string with pointer p after all the p++ operations as pointed out in other answer)

working code is below with these changes - note that best not use gets... scanf does the job...

```
      #include<stdio.h>
      #include<stdlib.h>

      void copystr(char *p,char *s);

    int main ()
    {

    char str[50],*ptr,*p;

   printf("enter the string\n");
   //       gets(str);
   scanf("%s",str);

      ptr=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
      copystr(ptr,str);

           printf("copy string is  %s\n", ptr);   // if i display this printf in main 'p' prints fine, but here no output
       free(ptr);

   //         getch();

     return 0;
  }

   void copystr(char *p,char *s)
 {          

     while(*s!='\0')
     {   *p=*s;
          s++;
          p++;
        }
        *p='\0';



       }
```

to make it work in the function .... see

```
      #include<stdio.h>
      #include<stdlib.h>

      void copystr(char *p,char *s);

    int main ()
    {

    char str[50],*ptr,*p;

   printf("enter the string\n");
   //       gets(str);
   scanf("%s",str);

      ptr=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
      copystr(ptr,str);

       free(ptr);

   //         getch();

     return 0;
  }

   void copystr(char *p,char *s)
 {          
     int i=0;
     while(*s!='\0')
   {   *(p+i)=*s;
          s++;
          i++;
        }
 *(p+i)='\0';

           printf("copy string is  %s\n", p);   // if i display this printf in main 'p' prints fine, but here no output


       }
```

Comment: i removed the malloc , but still no output

Comment: that's what i'm saying, the 'printf' working fine in main but not in function, i already did that

Comment: @madara - ok so the problem is that in the function p is too big because of all the p++ operations... see answer of Giorgi - I will change code to make it work in fuction as well - see edit in a moment.....